# Как увеличить скорость обновления записей в БД MySQL через скрипт?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть несколько файлов, в каждом файле более 10_000 строк вида "обновить поле, где id такое-то". Соответственно, я через Python отсплитил строки в массив.

Затем начал каждую запись записывать в БД синхронно. Все в принципе работает, на очень долго (за 12 часов обновилось только 15_000 записей)

Пробовал делать многопоточно (по 5, 20, 50 потоков) ни один из них не выполнил корректно 100 обновлений, т.к. выдавало ошибки долгого ожидания от MySQL.

Есть варианты как можно увеличить скорость записи или единственный путь получается - ждать синхронной записи?

Сейчас вот так работает:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text

HOST = ''
USER = ''
PASS = ''
PORT = ''
DB_NAME = ''
COUNT_FILES = 10

engine = create_engine(
    f'mysql://{USER}:{PASS}@{HOST}:{PORT}/{DB_NAME}', pool_size=30, max_overflow=15, pool_recycle=1200)

for number in range(1, COUNT_FILES):
    with open(f'SQL_update_{number}.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-16LE') as file:
        data_file = (file.read()).split(';')
        all_row = len(data_file)
        for number_row, UPDATE_DATA in enumerate(data_file, start=1):
            print(f'read file#{number} из {COUNT_FILES}; row #{number_row + new} из {all_row}')
            with engine.connect() as conn:
                sql_text = text(UPDATE_DATA)
                print(sql_text)
                conn.execute(sql_text)
                conn.commit()
```

UPDATE

Строки в файле вот такого вида:

```
UPDATE name_table SET name_field_table = 'ТУТ ОГРОМНАЯ СТРОКА НА 600 символов' WHERE id = <id_строки_в_таблице>
```

UPDATE2

Отправка пачками по 10 штук вида:

```
UPDATE name_table SET name_field_table = 'ТУТ ОГРОМНАЯ СТРОКА НА 600 символов' WHERE id = <id_строки_в_таблице>;
UPDATE name_table SET name_field_table = 'ТУТ ОГРОМНАЯ СТРОКА НА 600 символов' WHERE id = <id_строки_в_таблице>;
UPDATE name_table SET name_field_table = 'ТУТ ОГРОМНАЯ СТРОКА НА 600 символов' WHERE id = <id_строки_в_таблице>
....
```

в

```
conn.execute(sql_text)
```

просто зависает и не дает ответа, причем пачки формируются до

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос:  пример файла (4-5 строк), CREATE TABLE таблицы-приёмника, требуемое состояние данных в таблице после выполнения импорта показанных строк. PS. Сохранение по одной записи - это заведомо неверное и гарантированно медленное решение, и принципиально не ускоряется.

Comment: *Строки в файле вот такого вида* Если все строки представляют собой корректный SQL-код именно показанного вида, то есть как минимум 3 решения. Первое - всё содержимое файла как есть отправляется в user-defined переменную и затем выполняется как динамический SQL (PREPARE). Второе - из исходного файла вырезаются данные для обновления (строка и id), после чего формируется пакетное SQL-задание, выполняющее всё то же, но одним запросом. Третье - файл аплоадится на сервер и там выполняется через CLI.

Comment: А из простого можно попробовать создавать коннекшен один раз (ну или на каждый файл хотя бы), а коммиты делать по условию например `number_row % 1000 == 0` - один коммит на 1000 апдейтов, ну и в конце файла ещё раз коммит для остатков. Возможно, уже быстрее будет.

Comment: @CrazyElf Отдельные передачи по сети (плюс отдельный парсинг запросов в построителе плана на сервере) заведомо проиграют моим вариантам - однако по сравнению с исходным вариантом выполнение всего пакета в одной транзакции или чанками, несомненно, прирост к скорости даст... правда, от такой длинной транзакции может стать кисло конкурирующим клиентам.

Comment: @Akina А вот этого мы ничего не знаем - насчёт конкурирующих клиентов, есть ли они )  Я бы проверил ещё нет ли там каких индексов, триггеров и т.п. на этом поле. Может они ещё тормозят. И тогда типовой совет индекс отключить на время всей этой вставки.

Comment: Если вырезать информацию об обновлении и пакетом кинуть для записи, то получается, что для 1 файла общий вес будет 700 символов * 10_000 строк * 2 байта = 13 Мб запрос получится на обновление. Это нормально будет? Я просто где-то на форуме читал, что лучше по одной кидать

Comment: @CrazyElf У него, к сожалению, не вставка, а обновление. Там эффект от  удаления индексов с последующим пересозданием меньше. К тому же обновляется длинное строковое поле, каковые редко индексируют.. а снос и пересоздание FTI, скорее всего, будет медленнее.

Comment: *Я просто где-то на форуме читал, что лучше по одной кидать* Вас обманули. *13 Мб запрос получится на обновление. Это нормально будет?* Да нормально. Главное, не вылети за предельный размер входящего пакета (в смысле не забудь его проверить/увеличить, [@@max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet), session scope). Да и вообще, 13 метров передать по сети одной посылкой или 10к посылок - уже одно это по времени различается на три порядка. А в пределах одного хоста - где-то раз в 30..

Comment: @Akina, я попробовал пачками строки из файла, соединенные через ';', но он просто не обрабатывает - просто зависает и все. Что не так?

Comment: @Алексей А там вообще движок БД то справляется - память, проц, всего хватает? Может он там захлёбывается вообще? )

Comment: @CrazyElf, дак я для начала по 10 штук решил олтправлять (в обновлении показал что отправляю)

Comment: @Алексей Так, стоп, а для начала индекс по `id` то вообще есть в этой таблице? Простые селекты с `WHERE` по `id` быстро работают?

Comment: Там по ходу ограничения какие-то стоят, т.к. решил через DataGrid подключиться и выполнить такой запрос - он тоже не выполнился и зафейлился (на 10 записей)

Comment: *Что не так?* Для начала проверь, а умеет ли используемый метод выполнять пакетные, мультизапросы. Далеко не каждый метод это позволяет, а иногда нужно выставление соотв. флага выполнения.

Comment: Например, [MySQLCursor.execute()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) этого не умеет , тут нужен [MySQLCursor.executemany()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html), которому надо выделить и скормить массив параметров.

Comment: Вообще хорошо бы к вопросу прилагать описание таблицы. А лучше сгенерённый скрипт для её создания. С полями, индексами. Чтобы было хоть немного понятно, что там вообще и как.